# Formatting table of content, How to change dot to underscore character?

Tags: table-of-contents

I don't know how to change the default dot point separations between section names and page number to the continuous lines shown in the figure. The main issue is that i don't really know which package i should use, now i have toc. Can anyone help me, with a link or something?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a **KOMA-Script class** you can use

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% loads package tocbasic automatically

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  toclinefill=\enskip\hrulefill
]{section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{AAA}
\subsection{Aaaa}
\subsection{Abbb}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% loads package tocbasic automatically

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\enskip\hrulefill,
]{tocline}{section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{AAA}
\subsection{Aaaa}
\subsection{Abbb}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a **standard class** you could load package `tocbasic` and us `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\enskip\hrulefill,
]{tocline}{section}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{AAA}
\subsection{Aaaa}
\subsection{Abbb}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you can not use packages `tocbasic` and `tocloft` together in the same document.

Answer (score 3):

You have provided no information so far about which document class is employed by your LaTeX document. The working assumption of the following answer is that you use a document class that's compatible with the [tocloft](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}     % https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\renewcommand\cftdot{\rule{1ex}{.4pt}} % underscore-like object
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0} % no separation between the chars
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % enable leaders for section-level entries

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{AAA}
\subsection{Aaaa}
\subsection{Abbb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use a `\rule{.4pt}{.4pt}` instead of the underscore and set the `\cftdotsep` to 0? The rule can more easily be customized compared to the underscore.

Comment: @Skillmon - Many thanks for this suggestion! I've updated my answer accordingly. (Actually, I changed the width of the notional underscore character from `0.4pt` to `1ex`, but the idea is the same.)